# Why is my parsed JSON converting into a list python?

Tags: python, json, api, parsing, dictionary

I am trying to parse a JSON file from an api, and i am not sure why it's converting to a list.

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen
import json
Auth_key = 'get ur own key'
headers = {
  'Authorization': Auth_key
}
request = Request('https://app.com/orders?orderStatus=awaiting_shipment', headers=headers)

def remove_nulls(d):
    d = {k: v for k, v in d.iteritems() if v is not None}
    return { k:v for k, v in d.items() if v }

response_body = urlopen(request).read()

parsed = json.loads(response_body, object_hook=remove_nulls)
jsonData = parsed["orders"]
#print(json.dumps(jsonData, indent=1, sort_keys=True))
print type(jsonData)
```

When I check "parsed" it's a dict but "jsonData" is not. Thanks in advance

Comment: jsonData refers to a different object, obviously a list, in your json response, why it should be the same type than its container ?

Comment: Why does "parsed" convert to a list instead of staying as a dict?

Comment: `parsed` stays a dict, you're accessing `jsonData` type, not `parsed` type, `print type(parsed)` to check this

Comment: I'm sorry, i meant why "jsonData" is a list. 

   
My 'orders' has sub dictionaries, so i was trying to access those values.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing a `key` from your `dict` so it can be any other `datatype`.

This might be a case with you:

```
In [91]: jsonData = {'orders': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'others': {}}

In [92]: type(jsonData['orders'])
Out[92]: list
```

Comment: My 'orders' has sub dictionaries, so i was trying to access those values.

Comment: please share your dictionary.